# Spread function into React JS hook component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Is there a chance I can spread the `next` function (as in the example below) inside the `<ConfirmForm />` component? It looks as if PHPStorm throws the following error: `'next' is declared here. Block-scoped variable 'next' used before its declaration.`?

Error message:
`ReferenceError: Cannot access 'next' before initialization`

```
import useMultistepForm from 'Hooks/useMultipleStep';

const {
  step,
  back,
  goTo,
  isFirstStep,
  lastStepIndex
} = useMultistepForm([
  // Error appears here ->
  <ConfirmForm next={ next } />,
  <ConfirmCard />
]);
```

useMultistepForm hook:

```
export const useMultistepForm = (steps: ReactElement[]) => {
const [currentStepIndex, setCurrentStepIndex] = useState(0);

function next() {
  setCurrentStepIndex((i) => {
    if (i >= steps.length - 1) {
      return i;
    }

    return i + 1;
  });
}

return {
  next
};
```

Comment: Can you post the body of your component showing how `useMultistepForm` and `next` are defined in relation to each other? Also, can you confirm that the `used before its declaration` error is on the same line as `<ConfirmForm next={ next } />`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://tsplay.dev/NdEXkm. Please [edit] your question with a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the error you are getting.

Comment: @superhawk610 updated the code. did it become better now?

Comment: @AlexWayne you might not be able to reproduce it because of the sandbox you use. How do you think semantically is possible to use a function before declaration?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. `useMultistepForm()` returns `{ next }`, but then you seem to expect entirely different return values `step, back, goTo...`. And you also seem to want to use `next` in the parameters when you call `useMultistepForm`, but you cannot use a functions return value in it's own invocation. This is very confusing.

Comment: @AlexWayne, yes. so there is no 'easy workaround'?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if I understand you correctly, you want to provide a function called `next`, created by the hook, to the components that you are passing into that hook.

You can do that by making the hook accept a function, where the arguments of that function are provided by the hook.

```
function useMultistepForm(
    stepsFn: (next: () => void) => ReactElement[]
) {
  const [currentStepIndex, setCurrentStepIndex] = useState(0);

  function next() {
    setCurrentStepIndex((i) => {
      if (i >= steps.length - 1) {
        return i;
      }
      return i + 1;
    });
  }

  // Call the function to get the rendered components
  const steps = stepsFn(next)
  
  return { // whatever you need here.
    next,
    step: steps[currentStepIndex],
    back: () => undefined,
    goTo: () => undefined,
  }
}
```

Here the hook is typed to be passed a function. That function will accept a `next` function provided by the hook.

The return value of that function are the `steps`.

---

Then inside the hook, to get the actual steps, you need to invoke that function and pass it your `next` function.

That would be used like this:

```
const { step } = useMultistepForm((next) => [
    <ConfirmForm next={ next } />,
    <ConfirmCard />
]);
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYCiANkiEgHZZwCuAzkgMowoxJwC+cAZlBCHADkUAjEEAocdxoUMwCBVoMAsjWIxgdNmABi0EAApxcE3C1IwdHRQBccAxSQAPGHYMBKOAF4AfHABuEMAAJp6++OgwJGSUMADaALrinjjGcGgKWnBxaDRQIlTMFgCSFMHO2AwwAMJ5BTBFYKXlTgneSkwsbAYADO4A3JIm0rIaCnCOLh64aSZVtfmxjc3OBgbAYX6ppqbA3PbAcD5eZtp0AHSkFADmMAAWcAC0cACMKbM7cCIweYrAg59OB8TN9fnBDgBqV4A0wcAZpDhDdKZeDmSztNFWCgOZwwdxItKgqCKPAAelJcAA7ndWEh-EgoHAkMQGHAAJ4QGgTJBIYJwO4MpDnD6TLAfNF2TE5OpLbQrVqYD4AI3QAGs3JtaGUkNxgI5goqdtcIAAVCAa7x+GTlXX6w1AxFSGRycbVBS6qAgPSegxgPiWOx4UUW8KBEKcFJfJA-YlwAA8PjjpL8iJGLsUbooHpA1RQUGC0zwRMUCaTKckabGimUbLd4AUsULH3oSFU6k02m9hlFluywNMccz2a73JcXiDuM4cGT9sBg-dwE9ufz058HwS8MRQA) for a working example